# wordpress adds -s to http automatically

Tags: wordpress

I am using a webservice for finding ip's country info.When I use below code , wordpress automatically redirect "http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=jsonpCallback" to " https://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=jsonpCallback " and give this error."GET https://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=jsonpCallback net::ERR_CERT_REVOKED"

why worpress adds -s to my link.
how to fix this error.

Note: It works on Mozilla but at Chrome it does not work.
thank you.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            function jsonpCallback(data) { 
               console.log (data);

                    }        
       </script>
    <script src="http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=jsonpCallback"
     type="text/javascript"></script>

htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is your domain on a SSL? If you have https in your site url it will convert all internal links.

Check your .htacess for rewrites.

Comment: thank you for your answer ,yes my domain on a SSL , Which code should I change.I also add my htaccess.

Comment: I'm not sure does is somewhere in your database, but you can try to force that link with Better search replace plugin. 

You can search for this link `https://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=jsonpCallback` and replace it with `http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=jsonpCallback`

Answer (score 0):

check for this meta in your website source

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">`

Practically this redirect all http request to https, some SSL plugin for wordpress add this automatically or by setting an option.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code for a similar situation. I am not sure if it will help for yours though.

```
function fix_https_link($url, $path, $orig_scheme, $blog_id){

  $ssl_enabled = false;
  $options = get_blog_option($blog_id, "rlrsssl_options");

  if ($options && isset($options)) {
    $site_has_ssl = isset($options['site_has_ssl']) ? $options['site_has_ssl'] : FALSE;
    $ssl_enabled = isset($options['ssl_enabled']) ? $options['ssl_enabled'] : $site_has_ssl;
  }

  if (!$ssl_enabled) {
    $url = str_replace("https://","http://",$url);
  }
  return $url;
}
add_filter( 'home_url', 'fix_https_link' , 10,4);
```